# Returning function values in pair C

Tags: c

I am solving a problem in C, but I have difficulty in connecting parts of my script.

I define a type pair as follows:

```
typedef struct pair {
    double x, y;
} pair;
```

Now, I would like to return the values in the function as pairs but I don't understand how to do that.

```
pair predcorr(double t, double x, double y, double h) { 

    double Newx = x + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dxdt(t, x, y) + dxdt(t+h, x+(h*dxdt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dxdt(t, x, y))));
    double Newy = y + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dydt(t, x, y) + dydt(t+h, x+(h*dydt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dydt(t, x, y))));
    return ????,
```

How that would work, is it possible to provide me with some explanation?

Comment: Please note that it is usually a bad idea to pass structs by value to/from functions. This will make your program slower. As a rule of thumb in C, structs are always passed by reference. C programmers might actually find it odd and confusing to encounter a function passing by value.

Comment: You might want to create a helper function `struct pair make_pair(double x, double y) { struct pair ret; ret.x = x; ret.y = y; return ret; }`. With that in place, you can write `return make_pair(Newx, Newy)`. Note that it is somewhat unusual to pass structs by value in C, but far from being unheard of.

Comment: `return (pair){ Newx, Newy};` in C99;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to explain passing and returning structure values is with an example. When passing `complex data structures` to/from `functions`, the `struc`t is usually `passed and returned` as `a pointer`. This also requires that your function prototype return be consistent with the type you want returned. (this could just as well been declared as a `void` functions since the values for the `pair` are filled in during execution of the function itself.)

**Note:** to pass pair as a pointer, the struct `address` is passed to `predcorr`. So if you declare a static instance of `pair` you need to precede it with the `&` address of operator.

Here is a short example with made-up functions to show you how this would work with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pair {
    double x, y;
} pair;

double dxdt (double a, double b, double c)   /* totally made up functions */
{  return a*a + 2 * a * b + c * c;  }

double dydt (double a, double b, double c) 
{  return 2*a*a - 4 * a * b - 2 * c * c; }

/* function accepts and returns a pointer to struct pair */
pair *predcorr (pair *ptr, double t, double x, double y, double h) { 

    double Newx = x + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dxdt(t, x, y) + dxdt(t+h, x+(h*dxdt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dxdt(t, x, y))));
    double Newy = y + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dydt(t, x, y) + dydt(t+h, x+(h*dydt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dydt(t, x, y))));

    ptr-> x = Newx;
    ptr-> y = Newy;

    return ptr;
}

int main () {

    double t = 5;           /* made up initial example values   */
    double x = 2;
    double y = 7;
    double h = 3;

    pair mypair = {0,0};    /* declare instance of struct pair  */


    predcorr (&mypair, t, x, y, h); /* call predcorr pass ptr   */

    /* print the values as returned in mypair */
    printf ("\nThe Newx/Newy values are:\n\n");
    printf ("  Newx : %lf\n  Newy : %lf\n\n", mypair.x, mypair.y);

    return 0;
}
```

**output of (made-up) values:**

```
$./bin/dxyt

The Newx/Newy values are:

  Newx : 132336.500000
  Newy : -185504.000000
```

Your other option is to `dynamically allocate` new storage for a `struct pair` in `predcorr` each time it is called. You would not have to pass a pointer to the function, and you would simply `assign` the return of the function call to a pointer of `struct pair` in your `main` function. The only additional requirement is that you are now responsible for freeing the data associated with the return to prevent memory-leaks in your code. It's not hard, but takes just a little more effort that can confuse at this state of the game. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

The function has `pair` as it's return type. Therefore, you must return something of type `pair` - this should already give you a hint on what to do. You have to create a variable of this type, fill it with values (Newx and Newy) and return it. It works the same way as if you wanted to return an integer: Create it, fill it, return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pair result;
result.x = ...;
result.y = ...;
return result;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, return can only return one variable. To return more than one value [variable], you need to

1. either pass the variables as reference.
2. Use a structure to hold all the variables required to return a value.

Using second approach, you can use something like..

in caller :

```
typedef struct pair {
double a, b;
} pair;
pair pr;
pr  = predcorr(m, n, o, p);
```

the function

```
pair predcorr(double t, double x, double y, double h) 
{ 
    pair result;

    result.a  = x + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dxdt(t, x, y) + dxdt(t+h, x+(h*dxdt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dxdt(t, x, y))));
    result.b  = y + 1.0/2.0 * h * (dydt(t, x, y) + dydt(t+h, x+(h*dydt(t, x, y)), y+(h*dydt(t, x, y))));

    return result;
}
```

<sup>Notice the `return` *type* specified for the function. So, you should obviously return a variable of type `pair`.</sup>